# What is the best approach in php website to grab data from an API with ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I've to develop an online betting system in which I'll grab game details form JSONOdds. They says that they update their live match data after every 2 minutes... so I'll send request to their server after every two minutes... and i'll save these details in my DB, and my user request will be served form my local DB.

Now i've to create two version one updated and one which is being updated so that my user can view full details.

Now my question is that is my approach right? or is there some other approach to do that?

Comment: you can try using `CURL`

Comment: oh, you can use ajax long polling to achieve this. Ex. https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery

Comment: if i've 100 users and their session start on the same time then i think this will affect my server speed that server will send 100 requests at the same time...

Comment: Yes i'll fetch data with curl... but now the problem is how to manage so many requests and server speed smooth... even some time browser gets hanged when application is sending ajax request after 30 seconds...

Answer (score 0):

use curl

```
    $chg= curl_init( $yourapiurlhere);
    curl_setopt($chg, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($chg, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($chg, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result = curl_exec($chg);
    curl_close($chg);

    //$result has your data
```